# Read the second and later <p> tag using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have searched and tried various options to read the data that appear after first `<p>` tag in Python using Beautiful Soup. The HTML is as below:

```html
[<div class="user-review">\n<p><strong>THANKS TO MEDIMANAGE\r\n                                 \r\n                            \r\n                                </strong></p>

<p class="lnhgt"> </p><p>Hi Sandeep</p><br/><p>At the onset I would like to thank you very much for your assistance in selecting and purchasing health insurance for my family,</p><br/><p>I am really impressed with the TAT you have maintained and I highly appreciate your advice on which insurance to buy.</p><br/><p>I must say that medimanage has assisted me seamlessly, while I was in the corporate world and today it shows the same interest to help me as an individual.</p><br/><p>Thank you so much and god bless you. May you have all the strength and ability to support many more customers like me.</p><br/><p>Merry christmas and a very happy new year to you and your family.</p><br/>

\n
```

I have used beautifulSoup and using the code mentioned below, I am able to read first

tag text, that is "THANKS TO MEDIMANAGE".

```
rev_soup = BeautifulSoup(review.read())
for review in rev_soup.find_all("div",class_="user-review"):
    print(review.p.text)
```

What I need is to read the part which is enclosed within p class "lnhgt", i.e.

> "Hi Sandeep
>   At the onset I would like to thank you very much for your assistance in selecting and purchasing health insurance for my family,
>   I am really impressed with the TAT you have maintained and I highly appreciate your advice on which insurance to buy.
>   I must say that medimanage has assisted me seamlessly, while I was in the corporate world and today it shows the same interest to help me as an individual.
>   Thank you so much and god bless you. May you have all the strength and ability to support many more customers like me.
>   Merry christmas and a very happy new year to you and your family"

Comment: "Hi Sandeep.." is not enclosed within p class `lnhgt`.

Comment: It is actually, i might have missed to add more closing </p> tag

Comment: `<p class="lnhgt"> </p>`. Your `p` tag with class lnhgt is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p_tags = soup.find(class_="user-review").find_all('p')
for p in p_tags[1:]: #find all p tag and exclude the first one
    print(p.text)
```

out:

```
Hi Sandeep
At the onset I would like to thank you very much for your assistance in selecting and purchasing health insurance for my family,
I am really impressed with the TAT you have maintained and I highly appreciate your advice on which insurance to buy.
I must say that medimanage has assisted me seamlessly, while I was in the corporate world and today it shows the same interest to help me as an individual.
Thank you so much and god bless you. May you have all the strength and ability to support many more customers like me.
Merry christmas and a very happy new year to you and your family.
```

Edit:

```
p_tags = soup.find(class_="lnhgt").find_next_siblings('p')
for p in p_tags:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. This is working, howsoever, instead of getting the details using position based attributes as [1:], would it be better if we can get it using class marker "lnhgt". Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted.

```
for review in rev_soup.find_all("div",class_="user-review"):
    print(' '.join(i.text for i in review.find_all('p')[1:]))
```

Here for every `review`, I m find all `p`s then concatenating all except first one using `str.join`. Then printing it.